# pytorch torch.Tensor object has not ndim attribute

Tags: pytorch

I am running a program that uses pytorch.

I have one variable that is a `torch.Tensor`

When I try `a_tensor.ndim` it throws an error:  "Attribute Error Tensor object has no attribute 'ndim'"

However in my google colab environment, tensors *do* have that, and also there is the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.ndim.html#torch.Tensor.ndim)

Is it a matter of attributes added in latests versions?
I cannot for the moment change my pytorch version. Is there a way to get the info that `ndim` gives?

Comment: try checking your version of torch, the versions do affect, the version i'm using 1.7 does come with it

Comment: My version is 0.4.1. Pretty old I guess. Is there some equivalent for ndim in this?

Comment: Well there is len(a_tensor.shape), though its just counting the number of shapes

Comment: There's also `.dim()` for old versions of torch.